# How to integrate an Ingestion Flow Pipeline with AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, pipeline, aws-glue, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to create an Entire Data pipeline on AWS.
These are the components that I have planned on using:

- Data Source: This is a remote CSV file (let's say a file in GitHub).
- Data Lake: This will be an S3 bucket
- Ingestion flow: (**Problem I have** )To transfer data from the data source to the data lake.
- ETL flow: AWS Glue
- Data Warehouse: AWS Redshift(as Parquets)

My main problem is the ingestion flow. Is there a way to automatically download the remote CSV file into the s3 bucket as part of the Glue pipeline? Or should I use another service for this?

Finally, my aim is to create a single pipeline that will do the ingestion flow and ETL flow and save the data in the data warehouse.

Comment: Yes, I think this would be a good fit for Glue.  And I would use Python's Request module to handle the CSV download

Comment: @BobHaffner , just to clarify, I need to add the code downloading the remote CSV file within the glue script? Is a crawler needed for this process or will a simple function suffice?

Comment: Yes, within the Job script.  No need for a crawler